# Error: number of arguments and self

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to figure out how to use `numba` to best pre-compile a long running function and put it in a `QThread`. Unfortunately, I am running into a variety of issues (one even being `numba` not printing errors, just crashing the program).

I put together a small code sample to try to at least make that work, but thats still hitting issues.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

import workClass

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        t = workClass.longThread()
        t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**workclass.py**

```
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from numba import jit
import time

class longThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(longThread, self).__init__()
        return None

    def run(self):
        start = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        j = np.iinfo(np.long).max
        print(self.doStuff(j))
        print(str(int(round(time.time() * 1000)) - start))

    @jit("float64(int32)")
    def doStuff(j):

        for i in range(0, 1000000):
            j = np.sqrt(j)
        return j
```

When I run this, I get:

```
TypeError: too many arguments: expected 1, got 2 at print(self.doStuff(j))
```

I assume this is python passing `self` as well as `j`. But if I add `self` into the def for `doStuff`, then `numba` whines because it cant compile `self`. So, whats the proper way to set up `numba`?

I know is this particular instance, some things could be moved around, but this is set up as close to my real project as I could get it.

Incidentally, if I just replace the signature for `dostuff` with `nopython=True` and then add `self` as the first argument, it at least gets past that point and actually prints an error about compiling the type, which my real project refuses to do for some unknown reason I couldn't replicate.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a method at all?

Comment: from the docs, [@jit](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html) compiles functions and [@jitclass](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html) handles classes... with the warning _This is a early version of jitclass support. Not all compiling features are exposed or implemented, yet._. It would be wise to stick to functions, especially when the class is also a QT thing.

Comment: I'm not trying to precompile a class, just a single long running algorithm, the one function with the decorator

Answer (score 3):

You can try defining it as a [`staticmethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python):

```
@staticmethod
def doStuff(j):
    # code goes here
```

That way, you don't have to pass in the reference to `self`, and the method can still remain within the class.

Comment: i actually tried this as well, and numba complained. I dont remember what the exact message was and that project is on another computer not here.

Comment: @Bastiat It would be a good idea to edit your post and add the error message for this case as well.